# MPI_Bcast hanging after some data transferred

Tags: mpi, openmpi, infiniband

I am running application that performs some transformations of large matrices on 7-node cluster. Nodes are connected via QDR 40 Gbit Infiniband. Open MPI 1.4.3 is installed on the system.

Given matrix transformation requires large data exchange between nodes in such a way that at each algorithm step there is one node that sends data and all others receive. Number of processes is equal to number of nodes used. I have to say that I am relatively new at MPI, but it seemed that ideal way of performing this is by using MPI_Bcast.

Everything worked fine for some not so large matrices. However, when matrix size increases, at some point application hangs and stays there forever.

I am not completely sure, but it seems like there is no errors in my code. I traced it in detail in order to check if there are some uncompleted collective operations before that specific call of MPI_Bcast, but everything looks fine. Also, for that specific call, root is correctly set in all processes, as well as message type and size, and, of course, MPI_Bcast is called in all processes.

I also ran a lot of scenarios (running application on matrices of different sizes and changing the number of processes) in order to figure out when this happens. What can be observed is the following:

- for the matrix of the same size, application successfully finishes if I decrees number of processes
- however, for given number of processes application will hang for some slightly larger matrix
- for the given matrix size and number of processes where I have program hanging, if I reduce the size of the message in each MPI_Bcat call twice (of course the result will not be correct), there will not be hanging

So, it seems to me that problem could be in some buffers that MPI uses, and maybe some default MCA parameter should be changed, but, as I said, I do not have a lot of experience in MPI programming, and I have not find solution for this problem.
So, the question is whether anyone has had a similar problem, and maybe knows if this could be solved by setting appropriate MCA parameter, or knows any other solution or explanation?

Comment: Open MPI 1.4.3 is a very old piece of software. I would suggest that you ask on the [Open MPI users mailing list](http://www.open-mpi.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/users) if not already done so. By the way, how much data (in bytes) is being broadcasted?

Comment: Hristo, thank you for the quick response. Size of message goes from 50 to 200 MB. However, before that specific call of MPI_Bcast that hangs, I have a lot of MPI_Bcast calls with messages of the same size that successfully complete.

Comment: Have you tried the same code with another MPI implementation, e.g. MVAPICH or Intel MPI? The default broadcast algorithm for large messages that OMPI uses should not cause lock-ups unless something really wrong happens.

Comment: No, I have not tried any other MPI implementation, but I certainly will. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Hristo already mentioned, please start by using a newer OMPI version from the [Open MPI web site](http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/)
The current stable version is 1.6.5, so this is what you should get.
Chances are - this will make the problem go away.

If the problem persists, then the best way to deal with it is by discussing it on the OMPI users mailing list - folks over there will deal with it quickly.

If you still wish to play with MCA parameters, I suggest to start with these:

```
--mca btl_openib_flags <hex value>
--mca mpi_leave_pinned <0|1>
```

Comment: Given the way `MPI_Bcast` is implemented, I doubt that any of those flags would influence the OP's case.